# how to prevent current_user is nil in devise when putting logic in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code

```
- if current_user && !current_user.is_owner?(@product)
  p do this
```

I added the `current_user &&` logic because an error would occur if user is not logged in. but I am wondering if it is the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
- if user_signed_in? && !current_user.is_owner?(@product)
  p do this
```

Comment: but `current_user` is still nil in that case.

Comment: @ChrisYeung doing `- if current_user` and `- if user_signed_in?` is technically the same thing. `user_signed_in?` can express the internet better.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably end up having to work around other problems in your views if you need the views to process parameters from the logged on user.

I would recommend you add a `before_action` that redirect to the login page if the `current_user` variable is not populated.

something like:

```
class YourController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :redirectIfNoCurrentUser

  ** your functions/actions **

  def redirectIfNoCurrentUser
    redirect_to(new_user_session_path) unless current_user 
  end
end
```

`before_action` and `skip_before_action` [can be configured](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) in a per action basis with the `:only` option if required

Answer (score 1):

You are right, this is already the correct way of doing this.

After it checks and sees that `current_user` returns `false` it knows the conditional will be false and does not execute the second part of the conditional.

Answer (score 1):

It is a better practice of checking any value as `current_user.present?` instead of `current_user` because the previous one returns a boolean value.

You can try using `authenticate_user!` method of devise, If you do not want the user who is not logged in to access the page.

```
class YourController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:your_actions]

  def your_actions
  end

end
```

Then in your views you can handle your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, but if you want to avoid littering your code with nil checks you may wish to consider using the [null object pattern](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rails-refactoring-example-introduce-null-object) and make a NullUser with defined default behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try to use [try method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try).

```
if current_user.try(:is_owner?, @product)
  p do this
end
```